# Not getting mail sometimes from docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Sometimes we didn't get mail from DocuSign (for sign in document) so any history or log from DocuSign that you have send mail to customer.

My client problem : first time it has sent but mail has not received to client so client has resend for signing after he got mail and he signed but first time why he didn't got mail that we wanted check so kindly let us know if mail history or log is available?

Comment: Is there a programming question here somewhere? SO is for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

[DocuSign Support](https://support.docusign.com/) should be able to provide more information. I'd recommend you open a Support case and provide the envelope ID in question.

Checking your Spam folder is also a good idea. Info on whitelisting DocuSign emails is available here: https://support.docusign.com/articles/Why-am-I-not-getting-DocuSign-email-notifications